# 1 character filter in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Having a filter issue in angular.

Filtering in angular, the data filter happens when i type two characters, if i type 1 character, nothing happens.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="filterAge">

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="r in vm.Data | filter: filterAge">
    <td>{{r.Age}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> How do i make angular to do a filter for 1 character?

For example, if i type 1, it doesn't filter, if i type 19, it filters...

Comment: Your <tr> is not closed and needs to be in a <table> tag...

Comment: It's worth to mention that if you only want to filter items by age, you should do this: `<tr ng-repeat="r in vm.Data | filter: { Age: filterAge }">`

Comment: Actually the code uses fewer more properties for filtering, I have the same issue for other fields too, 1 character, nothing, happens, more than 1, filter happens, is there any length restriction happening here internally? for example, in auto-suggest we say maxLength for searching, for example:3, so when user types 3 characters, search happens, similarly, wondering if there is any length check happening inside filters? Can anyone help me if i need to create a custom filter?

Comment: @Sharpeye500 there's no restriction in AngularJs in-built filter. Can you create a snippet or a plunker to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You probably do not have any single digit values in vm.Data OR all your values include a '1' in them - try inputting using all digits from 0-9.

I have your filter working with single digits here:

https://jsfiddle.net/AKMorris/7xn77eeh/

Html:

```
<div data-ng-app='myApp' data-ng-controller='myCtrl'>

   <input type="text" ng-model="filterAge"/>

<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="r in vm.Data | filter: filterAge">
 <td>{{r.Age}}</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.vm = {};   
    $scope.vm.Data = [
    {"Age":19},
    {"Age":1},
    {"Age":2},
    {"Age":3},
    {"Age":22},
    {"Age":43}
    ];
});
```

Comment: Thanks, could it be having undefined or null when the value is not present?

Comment: nope angular will just skip those try typing "5" as the filter in the update here: https://jsfiddle.net/AKMorris/7xn77eeh/2/

Answer (score -2):

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in vm.Data | filter: filterAge>
```

You have missed the closing quotation mark (") at the end of the ng-repeat